# UIButton not changing image unless there's a background color

Tags: swift, uibutton

This is weird and I've tried different permutations of UIControl.State(). Unless I put in a background color to the image, the actual image doesn't change.

```
func followUserLocation {
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 500, width: 50, height: 50)
    
    if followUserStatus {
      followUserButton = UIImage(named: "follow_user_high")
      button.setImage(followUserButton, for: .normal)
      let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinatesToAppend, latitudinalMeters: 2500, longitudinalMeters: 2500)
      vcTrainMapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
      print("0 AA - TRUE \(followUserButton) \(UIControl.State())")
    } else {
      followUserButton = (UIImage(named: "follow_user"))
      button.setImage(followUserButton, for:.selected)
      print("0 BB- FALSE \(followUserButton) \(UIControl.State())")
    }

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

//    button.backgroundColor = .lightGray // Once I utilise this, it works.
    self.view.addSubview(button)
  }
```

Here's the print out put. The UIControl.State() also does not change when pressed.

```
0 AA - TRUE Optional(<UIImage:0x60000154b0f0 named(main: follow_user_high) {40, 40}>) UIControlState(rawValue: 0)
0 AA - TRUE Optional(<UIImage:0x60000154b0f0 named(main: follow_user_high) {40, 40}>) UIControlState(rawValue: 0)
0 BB- FALSE Optional(<UIImage:0x600001504a20 named(main: follow_user) {40, 40}>) UIControlState(rawValue: 0)
0 BB- FALSE Optional(<UIImage:0x600001504a20 named(main: follow_user) {40, 40}>) UIControlState(rawValue: 0)
0 AA - TRUE Optional(<UIImage:0x60000154b0f0 named(main: follow_user_high) {40, 40}>) UIControlState(rawValue: 0)
0 AA - TRUE Optional(<UIImage:0x60000154b0f0 named(main: follow_user_high) {40, 40}>) UIControlState(rawValue: 0)
0 AA - TRUE Optional(<UIImage:0x60000154b0f0 named(main: follow_user_high) {40, 40}>) UIControlState(rawValue: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove if statement then set your button image on both `.normal` and `.selected` states. After that, update the button selection state.

```swift
func followUserLocation {
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 500, width: 50, height: 50)

    followUserButton = UIImage(named: "follow_user_high")
    button.setImage(followUserButton, for:.selected)

    followUserButton = (UIImage(named: "follow_user"))
    button.setImage(followUserButton, for: .normal)

    if followUserStatus {
      let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinatesToAppend, latitudinalMeters: 2500, longitudinalMeters: 2500)
      vcTrainMapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
  }

@objc private func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
    print(sender.isSelected)
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I did add some printout before and after pressing the button and it still shows the image is named "follow user". When I swapped the codes such that "follow_user_high" is the 2nd code sequence then it would work for 1st press (tho the printout still shows doesn't change - but will show "follow_user_high" as this is the latest code sequence). When pressed again, the button doesn't change anymore.

Comment: How did you add the code to test? I am not sure how it's printed but you can see the image changed on the button when pressing.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. The image doesn't change. See this screen recording https://www.dropbox.com/s/klr2k6b16fck98q/dvvva.mov?dl=0